# Sending HTML content to react application from npm package

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm building a npm package which should send some html content to react/angular/vue applications.

I have build a static html page and tried loading that file using below code, which is giving me the expected buffer when executing 
`node index.js`
but when installed the above package in my react app.
it is giving fs.readFileSync is not a function.,

```
function generateHTML() {
    const appRoot = process.cwd();
    var html = fs.readFileSync(appRoot + '/wallet/pages/signup.html');
    return html;
}
```

from my knowledge 'fs' module will only work in node environment, so how i can achieve providing node environment when npm package is installed as dependency to react app.

Comment: why are you trying to send html to react? with react you can create any required html independently

Comment: that package is like a Generic package which serves any application using any framework(react,angular,vue)

Comment: I'm trying to build an npm package , so it doesn't solves issue.
FYI :  i packed the same using ```npm pack``` and installed (.tgz file) in sample react app to make use of it.

Comment: @PrasanthVuppala Did you ever find a solution to this?